# TransportInterface y TransportModel que propone FreeRTOS. Cambio de contexto

Tags: arduino, esp32

El problema radica en la implementación del modelo Transport para distintas redes y conexiones que propone FreeRTOS.

Proyecto en el que trabajo se basa en un dispositivo (ESP32 240Mhz, DualCore) del que voy a utilizar tanto su interface wifi como el GSM (capa física),
sobre los cuales uso un stack tcpip para conectarme simultáneamente a un servidor, y a otro dispositivo ESP32.
Al otro dispositivo ESP32 le abro hasta 2/3 dos conexiones (una de control y otras(1/2)
para transferencia de audio o mensajes) y cualquiera de los 2 puede actuar como cliente o como servidor,
por lo que pueden inciar la conexion o aceptar la entrante.

En total, hablamos de 2 capas físicas y 1 de red, pero para 4 conexiones.

Espero haberlo descrito bastante claro.

Los problemas empiezan cuando las diferentes tareas (task's en FreeRTOS) intentar cambiar el contexto de red "NetworkContext" para realizar su trabajo.
Si no uso semáforos, se producen choques en los punteros a las funciones Send,Recv, etc etc y si uso semáforos para ir cambiando de contexto, se vuelve realmente lento, dado que en cada cambio de contexto se han de copiar todos los punteros a las funciones principales. Para un estado de semiactividad, no es problemático, pero cuando hay carga de trabajo o varias conexiones transmitiendo, la velocidad cae drásticamente, mucho mucho mas que si no uso el modelo propuesto "TransportModel".

Las pregunta es...

Hay alguna forma de usar el TransportInterface que propone FreeRTOS sin tener que hacer el switch para cada mensaje que viene o va a otro contexto ?

No ha problema en adjuntar toda mi implementación del modelo. Esta hecho en C/C++ para Arduino.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda u orientación. Puede que no tenga del todo claro el correcto uso del modelo, pese a que me he visto, descargado y probado los pocos ejemplos que encontré.

Gracias a tod@s.

Comment: Cambiate a MicroPython y deja de sufrir. Tiene soporte de thread y asyncio.

Comment: Ufff, a estas alturas se me hace cuesta arriba pasarme a Python, sobre todo por la cantidad de programas y código que tengo en C. La versión que tengo sin usar el modelo de transporte (sockets a pelo) funciona como un reloj y muy muy rápido. Todo ha surgido al querer implementar el modelo por capas que recomiendan los de FreeRTOS, pero que a la hora de la verdad, solo dan 2 ejemplos y muy muy poca documentación. Los ejemplos que dan, no me sirven dado que solo gestionan una conexión con MQTT, por lo que no me sirve ni de ejemplo. :-(